# Como remover palavra especifica da string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

tenho um input onde o usuario pode inserir o proprio site, e insiro o http:// ao gravar no db, mas gostaria de tratar para que caso ja exista essa tag no input ele nao inserir novamente, pois qnd o usuario atualiza ele inseri novamente a tag e fica http://http://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poder usar [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
let uri = 'meusite.com'

// -1 é não encontrado
if (uri.indexOf('http://') == -1 && uri.indexOf('https://') == -1){
   uri = 'http://' + uri;
}
```

Comment: Acho que esta é a melhor resposta, para não inserir `http` caso o input já tenha. Mas acho que devias verificar `https` também. `+1`

Comment: Consegui fazer oque eu precisava aqui, deu certinho, brigadãoo

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer assim:

```js
let url = "https://google.com";

let novaUrl = url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');

console.log(novaUrl);
```

Answer (score 4):

Um simples `replace` funciona.

Também poderia usar uma regex no replace, pra remover tanto "http://" quanto "https://".

```js
let input = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com';
input = input.replace('http://', '');

console.log(input);

let input2 = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com';
input2 = input2.replace(/^https?:\/\//,'', '');

console.log(input2);
```